# Which indexers can be disabled from Magento 2 if I am not using Magento's frontend?

Tags: magento2, indexing

I am planning to use Magento's database and rest api to add/update/get data. Customer facing interface will be written in viewjs (Not using Magento's frontend).

As we know few data is indexed in Magento's index tables for fast serving of data to frontend. If there is a change in original data, once indexer runs, these index tables are update.

> For example,
>
> if qty is update for a product via **rest-api/admin panel**, it
>   updates **`cataloginventory_stock_item`** table. and we can use rest
>   api **(`http://127.0.0.1/magento/rest/V1/stockItems/sku_code`)** to
>   get latest inventory data, even without running indexing.

Since I am not planning to use Magento's frontend, I believe I can disable a few indexers from our project?

Can you please let me know which indexers can be disabled if I am not using Magento's frontend ?

Answer (score 0):

None of them. All indexes are not only used by the frontend but also by the adminhtml.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this further, or do you have any source maybe? It seems to me that `catalogsearch_fulltext` is not used in the backend since it is frontend catalog product search (but I might be wrong).